# How to access the method in another method?

Tags: java, method-call

In this code, i am not able to call the **user()** method in **facto1()** method but I am not able to access the value of n in for loop

```
import java.util.*;    
public class fecto {
    //Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    //int n;
    
    public int user() {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n;
        System.out.println("Enter the number:");
        n = sc.nextInt();
        return n;
    }
    
    public int facto1() {
        int i, fac = 1;
        //int p = user();
        //System.out.println(p);
        user()
        for (i = 0; i <= n; i++) {
            fac = fac * i;
        }
        return fac;
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        fecto fe = new fecto();
        fe.facto1();
    }
}
```

Comment: what is problm.. i can see .. yes your logic is not very correct

Comment: And by the way, please start class names with an uppercase letter. It*s a general Java naming convention

Answer (score 0):

The call to `user()` does not store the result locally. Change

```
//int p = user();
//System.out.println(p);
user()
for (i = 0; i <= n; i++) {
```

to

```
int n = user(); // <-- you want `n`, not `p`.
for (i = 1; i <= n; i++) { // <-- 0 * x == 0, do not start with i = 0
```

Further, in `main` you aren't printing the result.

```
fecto fe = new fecto();
int result = fe.facto1();
System.out.println(result);
```